# Expresso Store - Register as a member during checkout errors

Tags: expresso-store, members

I am having problems registering a member during checkout.

My checkout works fine as long as the user does try to register as a member, the payment is approved, the order appears in the system with the default status applied and the user is correctly returned to the order confirmation screen as specified in the return parameter of the exp:store:checkout tag.

If the user tries to register as a member as they checkout the following happens.

1) The user is returned to the second of our 3 step checkout process - the billing / shipping address screen.  This is the page where the 'become member' checkbox and form is.

2) The site shows that they are now logged in. Additionally - The Basket still has their items in. Basket cookies haven't cleared.

2) Checking in the admin, the member has been created

4) The order has been received - marked as 'paid' BUT no status has been applied (and no email sent) & the members account hasn't been assigned to the order.

I originally had my order fields mapping to member fields, but have removed the mapping and the problems remain.

I am using the latest version of Store 1.6.3 and expression engine 2.5.5.

I'm a bit stuck how to debug this as no error codes are appearing on any of the pages.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Which payment gateway?

Comment: This sounds like a curly one. Can you email support@exp-resso.com so we can take a look at your site directly? Thanks

Comment: Hi Adrian - I have emailed support@exp-resso.com at 14:39 GMT today.

Comment: Ok great. Will follow up there!

Comment: You might want to also make sure that you have inline error handling turned off in those templates and that you do not have any custom member fields set to required in the EE CP and instead allow them to be set as required at the template level.

Comment: Hi Justin, There are no required custom member fields, and I still get the same issues when inline errors are turned off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a conflict with the [Twomile Login Redirect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/login-redirect) extension.

While Store was half way through processing the order, the member account is registered using the standard EE member registration functions (which I believe triggers the `member_member_login_single` hook since the member is logged in automatically). However, at this point the Twomile extension sees the member login and immediately redirects the customer back to the previous page (which results in an incomplete order and the customer's cart not being cleared).

The solution is to disable/uninstall Twomile Login Redirect. You can achieve the same things that extension provides on a per-template basis using [FreeMember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember) or any other member management plugins.

Comment: Just came across this exact same problem, thanks!